# Get Google Map Path Between my Location and a marker Ionic2

Tags: google-maps, localization, geolocation, ionic2

I have marker on my map and my actual position i want to get path as soon as i click on a marker!

[image: Like This]

Comment: Where is the issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think what you need here is the [Direction Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). You can calculate directions (using a variety of methods of transportation) by using the DirectionsService object. This object communicates with the Google Maps API Directions Service which receives direction requests and returns an efficient path. Then use Polylines for the path or the direction. Here is the sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ntcc2vaw/) that do this and use a dotted polyline for the directions.

Comment: @KENdi Thank you soo much for your response, so my problem i want to as soon as i click on a marker ( that i have on my data/location.json ) i want to get the path !